# PowerShell - extract text from text file one field from first line and second from second line

Tags: powershell

P.S: it's a text file containing lots of lines of data in the exact same format as shown below, and yes '3160 50' are constant and always stay the same.

This is a continuation of the previous part, I tried many different ways but was not successful, do anyone know how to extract the data from this text file.

```
 AK0002 3160
50 C2194123
 AK11234 3160
50 C2194567
 AK12321 3160
50 C2194224
 ARDEEP 3160
50 C2194444
 A11K 3160
50 C2197133
 ASTADDI3 3160
50 C2201234
 AY51212 3160
50 C2179874
 SOOPUSI 3160
```

Desired output:

```
AK0002 C2194123
AK11234 C2194567
AK12321 C2194224
ARDEEP C2194444
A11K C2197133
```

essentially want to get rid of 3160 50 and new line.

If anyone can help that will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You should go back to your previous question, there might be a way to get the desired result with the original file without this extra work (extra parsing)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I'm trying since morning and tried almost all variants like split, replace, selecting, etc. I thought if I just post this part of the questions, I might get some results.

Comment: I agree with @Santiago - it's better to solve the original problem. Lee has provided a detailed answer, and you could continue to work with him to solve your problem. I've also just posted a more concise, regex-based solution.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I will continue working there as well but had a hiccup with new solutions as well.